# Default interceptor and startup bean not working together EJB 3.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.1

When am try to deployed **startup** bean and **default interceptor** (through ejb-jar.xml) in JBOSS am getting below mentioned error.

```
DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=plmislapp.ear,jar=islbl.jar,name=CALCacheBaseLoader,service=EJB3_endpoint" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.j2ee:ear=plmislapp.ear,jar=islbl.jar,name=CALCacheBaseLoader,service=EJB3" (should be in state "Installed", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.j2ee:ear=plmislapp.ear,jar=islbl.jar,name=CALCacheBaseLoader,service=EJB3' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.j2ee:ear=plmislapp.ear,jar=islbl.jar,name=CALCacheBaseLoader,service=EJB3" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.j2ee:ear=plmislapp.ear,jar=islbl.jar,name=CALCacheBaseLoader,service=EJB3' **
```

**CALCacheBaseLoader** is my Startup bean

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@ExcludeDefaultInterceptors
public class CALCacheBaseLoader extends BaseBL {

    private static final String CURRENT_CLASSNAME="CALCacheBaseLoader";



    /**
     * This is method is called by container during server startup.
     * */
    @PostConstruct
    public void applicationStartup() {
        logInfo(CURRENT_CLASSNAME, "START METHOD:> applicationStartup");

        try{
            new CALCacheManagerWithJBossCache();
        }catch(Exception e){
            logError(CURRENT_CLASSNAME, CacheConstant.EXCEPTION_WHILE_REGISTER_CACHE);
            logStackTrace(CURRENT_CLASSNAME, "applicationStartup", CacheConstant.EXCEPTION_WHILE_REGISTER_CACHE, e);
        }
        logInfo(CURRENT_CLASSNAME, "END METHOD:> applicationStartup");
    }
}
```

and below is configuration for **default interceptor** in **ejb-jar.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  version="3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">

<interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>util.logger.SampleInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor>
</interceptors>

   <assembly-descriptor>
      <interceptor-binding>
         <ejb-name>*</ejb-name>
         <interceptor-class>util.logger.SampleInterceptor</interceptor-class>
      </interceptor-binding>
   </assembly-descriptor>   
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: A stab in the dark: try updating your ejb-jar.xml to use the 3.1 spec schema; it's currently using the 3.0 version. You need to provide more light by adding the stack traces that should be visible earlier in the logs.

Comment: yeah that's right yesterday i changed the version from 3.0 to 3.1 and it's working fine.